# Google markers not showing up

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

I want to use Google API to show route between **A** and **B** point and show all company's locations as marker. Showing route works well. But markers not displaying and showing no error.

Here is my code:

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);

function initMap() {
    //create map
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOptions);

    ContextMenu = document.getElementById("my-context-menu");
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function (ev) {
        currentLatLng = ev.latLng;
        console.log(ev.latLng);
        ShowContextMenuGoolge(ContextMenu, ev);

        /** this stop NOT stopping DOM 'context-menu' event from firing */
        ev.stop();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function () {
        HideContextMenuGoolge(ContextMenu);
    });

    //create a DirectionsService object to use the route method and get a result for our request
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    //create a DirectionsRenderer object which we will use to display the route
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

    //bind the DirectionsRenderer to the map
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: getAllMarkers,
        success: function (res) {
            createMarker(res);
        },
        err: function (err) {},
    });
}

function createMarker(companies) {
    // console.log(map);
    companies.map((el) => {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(el.lat, el.lng),
            map: map,
        });
        comMarkers.push(marker);
    });
    console.log(comMarkers);
}
```

This is result SS. Calculating route is works fine.
[image]

Thank for helping me.

Comment: What do you have when you log companies in `createMarker`?

Comment: It gives all companies name, lat and lng coordinates. And this request is working fine.

Comment: [{id: 1, name: "companyName", lat: "55.5555", lnt: "66.666"}]

Comment: I suppose it is lng instead of lnt that you just wrote ?

Comment: Thnks. I was wrong. I wrote my backend code.